# How safe are perfumes in different kinds of light?

Tags: visible-light

Odd question that may seem out of place but I think it's appropriate here!

**Perfumes degrade based on:**

- High temperatures
- High humidity (such as in a bathroom)
- UV exposure

The last aspect is what I'm focusing on. My question simply is: **how big of a difference in UV ray strength is there in the following circumstances (quantitatively):**

- What is the UV ray strength in typical direct sunlight?
- How about filtered through clouds?
- How about indirect sunlight through a window? (Such as a south/north-facing window which never gets direct sun exposure, for example)

I hope despite being in a perfume context, that this question is still physics-relevant (it is in my eyes, as I am interested in quantitative aspects of light.)

Comment: If the perfume is degrading, the human likely is too...

Comment: @JonCuster They do, it is called sunburn. As they are opaque it only affects the surface.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight):

> The total amount of energy received at ground level from the Sun at the zenith depends on the distance to the Sun and thus on the time of year. It is about 3.3% higher than average in January and 3.3% lower in July (see below). If the extraterrestrial solar radiation is 1367 watts per square meter (the value when the Earth–Sun distance is 1 astronomical unit), then the direct sunlight at Earth's surface when the Sun is at the zenith is about 1050 W/m<sup>2</sup>, but the total amount (direct and indirect from the atmosphere) hitting the ground is around 1120 W/m<sup>2</sup>.<sup>[3]</sup> In terms of energy, sunlight at Earth's surface is around 52 to 55 percent infrared (above 700 nm), 42 to 43 percent visible (400 to 700 nm), and 3 to 5 percent ultraviolet (below 400 nm).<sup>[4]</sup>

So a reasonable estimate of the UV ray strength in direct sunlight is probably 40 W/m<sup>2</sup>. Filtered through clouds, it will depend on the cloud cover.

Both direct and indirect sunlight through a window will have much, much lower UV exposure Glass is known to be a good UV absorber, with [one result on Google](http://www.shimadzu.com/an/industry/ceramicsmetalsmining/chem0501005.htm) showing a strong cutoff somewhere in the 300-350 nm range, which is still UVA and can only damage chemicals indirectly (by, say, forming free radicals). As a really rough guess (since I don't know the exact ratios etc.) I'd say you could probably cut down this number by at least a fraction of $1/4$, probably more, so we're down to the 5-10 W/m<sup>2</sup> range.

Indirect sunlight through a window is going to be negligible unless you're working on the timescales that, say, libraries have to preserve books over.